# how to define global constants in codeigniter in constants.php

Tags: php, codeigniter, constants

I have stored my global constants in config->constants.php but it creating problem and throwing error
I have defined it like this, how to call it in controller,
**code**

```
define('SuperAdmin','1');
define('Admin','2');
define('CityAdmin' '3');
define('SupportAdmin','4');
define('RestaurantUser','5');
define('FrontUser','6');
define('Other','7');
```

Comment: when i put constabnts in auto load
Severity: Notice

Message: Constant FILE_READ_MODE already defined

Filename: config/constants.php

Line Number: 16...this kind of error is generated for all constants defined in constants.php

Comment: and at last
Your applicationfiles/config/constants.php file does not appear to contain a valid configuration array.

Comment: dude i know why you are creating like this. Better you do this in database level.....

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You don't need to load constants anywhere, they're automatically autoloaded by CI itself, that is the point of them. To use them keep in mind they are constants and not a variable as you're used to with the $. So in your case after defining them, anywhere in your application you could for example use:

```
if($user->userType == SuperAdmin)
{
   do something here;
}
```

Note that the SuperAdmin is written without a $ preceding it and not inside quotes. Again, after defining them in the constants file you need to do nothing else to begin using them in your application.

Answer (score 7):

First of all use the conventions that you must define the constants in capital letters. Like

```
define('SUPERADMIN','1');
define('ADMIN','2');
define('CITYADMIN' '3');
```

you can use the constants in controller like

```
if($user->userType == SUPERADMIN)
{
   //Your code ...
}
```

and if you want to use in html file/ view file in codeigniter you can use constants in html file like

```
<?php echo SUPERADMIN; ?>
```

You can access the constants in this way.

Answer (score 2):

Always follow naming convention for constant in only capital letter. If you declared constant in application/config/constants.php file then it will available through out your application.

Comment: If you declared constants as: define('USER_TYPE','Super_admin');

Comment: You can access in controllers like:
You can access like USER_TYPE not $USER_TYPE.

if($user->userType == USER_TYPE)
{
    //You got here
}

Comment: Rather than adding to your answer with comments, you can click on the "edit" below the answer and then add the extra details.

Answer (score 0):

This is a correct way to define global constants in `config->constants.php`. Can you provide the detail about the error that your are facing and code where your are trying to use these variables.Keep in mind that these variables not need `$` sign to use.
Like it can be used as `$a = SuperAdmin` not as `$a = $SuperAdmin`

Comment: thanks for the answer i want to use it in the controller ,can you just tell me how to load constants.php fle in controller,like $this->load->config(constants); is it the correct way

Comment: ohk thanks everyone , Igot this and used as well but its cretaing problem for me when i used them in Where_in condition is der any sollution for that
Code
$data['user_array'] = $this->admin_model->get_dropdown('tk_rolemaster','Name,Id'," WHERE Status='Enable' AND Id IN (5,6)")->result();
Model code
 public function get_dropdown($table,$value,$where)
 {  
   return $this->db->query("SELECT ".$value." FROM ".$table." ".$where." "); 
 }

Answer (score 0):

You may utilise config file (system/application/config/config.php) to set configuration related variables.

Or use constant file (system/application/config/constants.php) to store site preference constants.